# How can I read my app's database file from device?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am writing an Android application using SQLite. How to view the .db file that's on the device without rooting it?

I tried Questiod SQLite Manager but "data/data/(my application name)/.db" cannot be opened. The method seems to be used for emulator and rooted devices only. I am using an unrooted device for debugging.

Screen for DDMS:

[image: Cap screen of DDMS]

Comment: intellij ultimate lets u do it, however its a paid ide.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , there are 2 methods from which u can view ur db data :

Go To DDMS ->  Data -> Data -> Select ur Package ->Databases -> Pull them Out and view with [SQlite Broswer](http://sqlitebrowser.org/)

OR

Install [Root Apk](http://www.appsapk.com/root-explorer/) in ur bluestack and view in device or emulator itself..

From Command Prompt you can try this

```
Open cmd
Go into 'Platform tools'
Type 'adb shell'
su
Press 'Allow' on device
chmod 777 /data /data/data /data/data/com.application.package /data/data/com.application.package/*
Open DDMS view in Eclipse and from there open 'FileExplorer' to get your desired file
```

[image]

Comment: @Helloheyyyy what r u using for debuging device or emulator or bluestack?

Comment: @mona Go To DDMS -> Data  <---Does it mean the Data folder under File Explorer in main window?? If yes, there is nothing under my data folder. Do I need to adjust some setting for my device or Eclipse???

Comment: @mona I am using a device,which is a Nexus 5

Comment: @Helloheyyyy ok so this much easily work for you..did u tried?

Comment: @mona I tried but i can't access to DDMS -> Data -> Data. There is no file in DDMS -> Data. Should I press any button like "Build All" before I do the following steps?

Comment: ohh ok , u can u root apk as well , but if u want to access from ddms u need to access from command promt see this : Open cmd
Change your directory and go into 'Platform tools'
Type 'adb shell'
su
Press 'Allow' on device
chmod 777 /data /data/data /data/data/com.application.package /data/data/com.application.package/*
Open DDMS view in Eclipse and from there open 'FileExplorer' to get your desired file

Comment: one more simple option is install bluestack that will give easy acess to you to root and do all possible think there

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file, add a property 'debuggable=true' in application tag. Then find your database in your given path.

Comment: This method does not work.When I hard code the property, "Avoid hardcoding the debug mode; leaving it out allows debug and release builds to automatically assign one" was prompted out and the project cannot be built.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean for debugging?

You could copy the database file to a non-private directory (for example into the one returned by [`Context.getExternalFilesDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDirs%28java.lang.String%29). Afterwards you can use [`adb pull`](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#commandsummary) to copy it to your development machine.

Answer (score 0):

Install this **[APK](https://www.dropbox.com/s/irquka2js5svkfr/SQLite%20Editor%20Pro-com.htsoft.sqleditor-30-v3.0.0.apk)** into your emulator and read your DB file and also add,update,delete record of  your database

[image]

Comment: What about if am using a device?

Comment: you can also use this app in devise also but need rooted device :)

Comment: nope not all the root apk need rooted device..try once and see ..it give access to ur data data folder

Comment: i use genymotion as my emulator so i don't need to use physical device if you try on non rooted and useful to than let me know also try this http://blog.shvetsov.com/2013/02/access-android-app-data-without-root.html

Answer (score 0):

You can view (visualize) the data in the .db file by using the software called "DB Browser for SQLITE"

1. get your .db file from the device(smartphone) memory (by accessing the DDMS --> File explore)
2. download and install sqlitebrowser (http://sqlitebrowser.org/)
3. after installing, open "DB Browser for SQLITE" and go to "open database" to load your .db file
4. Choose the "Browse data" tab
5. Finally, select the table you want to visualize to display the data in the database. [image]